# UIDocumentInteractionController view doesn't show up

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiactivityviewcontroller, uidocumentinteraction

I am trying to share a pdf, that I create within the app, with other apps using `UIDocumentInteractionController`. The same thing was working with `UIActivityViewController`.

To do that I call `- presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated:` method which returns `YES` but nothing shows up on the screen.

```
// view is a UIWindow
- (void)openDocumentFromRect:(UIView*)view withURL:(NSURL*)url {
    UIDocumentInteractionController *documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
    // the following returns YES
    [documentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:[view frame] inView:view animated:YES];
}
```

Any ideas why ?

Comment: What is your `url` ?

Comment: @MidhunMP url is something like: `file:///Users/[USER]/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[DEVICE]/data/Containers/Data/Application/[APP]/Library/TICKET.pdf`

Comment: @MidhunMP This is what I have on an actual device : `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/[APP]/Library/GMS-E-TICKET.pdf`. Doesn't change much. You probably just wanted to see if I had the `file://` I guess

Comment: Check whether the view frame is correct or for testing a custom specified rect.

Comment: @MidhunMP The frame is (0, 0, 320, 568)(iPhone5) so it is okay. Is it possible that the view is not displayed on top of all the others ?

Comment: I got the issue, specify a custom frame like  (150,150, 320, 568). The issue is the menu controller anchor is in 0,0 and your menu will be out of the view

Comment: @MidhunMP Nop, still no showing

Comment: @MidhunMP I've managed to make it work. Instead of presenting it in `window` I'm presenting it in `window.rootViewController.view`

Comment: @MidhunMP Thanks for your help! Any ideas why it wouldn't show up if presented in `window` ?

Comment: Why can't you just use `self.view` instead of `window.rootViewController.view` ?

Comment: @MidhunMP Because `self` doesn't have a `.view`. This is done "outside" of the actual app, in a lib, where I just have access to `window`.